# PHP - best practice to call a function twice with a different param

Tags: php

I have the following function:

```
function sortRelevantId($idArray, $maxIds, $xml, $idTpe)
{
    for ($i = count($idArray); $i < $maxIds; $i++) {
        if ($xml->sub[$i]->type == $idTpe) {
            $idArray[] = $i;
        }
    }
    return $idArray;
}



I call these like so, 
$idArray = [];
$idArray= sortRelevantId($idArray , $maxIds, $xml, "a");
$idArray= sortRelevantId($idArray , $maxIds, $xml, "b");
```

I am wondering how I can change the function so that I only need to call the function one and the logic in the function after type "a" and recall/ reruns for type "b"  ("a" takes priority over "b")

Thanks for any help

Comment: I would have done that instead of calling the method twice, pass an array of values to the ``idTpe= ['a', 'b']`` parameter then  ``if (in_array($xml->sub[$i]->type, $idTpe))`` soemthing like this.

Comment: @user19517065 Are you sure you wanted to do it the way shown by the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your codes as below.

```
function sortRelevantId($idArray, $maxIds, $xml, array $idTpe)
{
    $idArray = array();
    for ($i = count($idArray); $i < $maxIds; $i++) {
      foreach($idTpe as $item) {
        if ($xml->sub[$i]->type == $item) {
            $idArray[] = $i;
        }
      }
    }
    return $idArray;
}

$idArray= sortRelevantId($idArray , $maxIds, $xml, array("a","b"));
```

Comment: instead of using another``foreach($idTpe as $item)``, you can do ``if (in_array($xml->sub[$i]->type, $idTpe)) { ... }``

Comment: Yes, it can be so if the conditions are suitable. But since we can't see the whole code, it would be more correct for us to write it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) for this by passing output of one result as input to the other and finally returning the value.

```
<?php

$idArray = array_reduce(["a", "b"], fn($carry, $item) => sortRelevantId($carry, $maxIds, $xml, $item), []);

print_r($idArray);
```